# Django equivalent to mako's callable blocks

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mako

Is there a Django equivalent to Mako's callable blocks?

In Mako, if I have a particular bit of HTML that I would like to reuse, I can put it in a "callable block" which can be called from multiple places in the template.

```
<%def name="makerow(row)">
    <tr>
    % for name in row:
        <td>${name}</td>\
    % endfor
    </tr>
</%def>
```

Does Django have something similar to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django you can include other HTML templates to accomplish this:

```
{% include "main/includes/subtemplate.html" %}
```

You can access the same variables in the included template as in the parent template from which it is included. This allows you to reuse HTML in multiple places in a template.

An alternative is to create a custom template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/ This allows you to create your own tags that generate HTML output. The Django documentation provides various examples on how to do this.

Comment: It would be handy not to have to make a new file for each "template function".

Comment: +1 for the template tag, though it's not as easy as one would think as you'd need to pull the contents of the tag without converting django variables, then re-render the contents later.

Comment: Django templates are *intentionally* restrictive, because the philosophy is that you shouldn't be doing stuff like this in the template. Whether you agree or not (I do), that's the way Django is. Your recourse are template includes and template tags which give you much the same functionality, without cluttering the template.

Comment: I first thought template tag myself. For example you have the function get_related for a particular model Foo. {% get_related %} could populate your template with the infomration that you need. A much more resource intensive, but sometimes necessary is to create your own custom context processor. Be warned though that this is not efficient in most cases and context processors are the main cause of slowdown/bottleneck for the Django template language.